# Map range from 2 columns based on overlapping range in another Pandas dataframe and sum values for same range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two datasets (`df1` and `df2`) of values with a certain range (`Start` and `End`) in both of them.

I would like to annotate the first one (`df1`) with values from column `Num` of the corresponding overlapping range of values (`Start`/`End`) on `df2`.

Example: The first row in `df1` ranges from `0`-`2300000`, since `2300000` is lower than the `End` in first row in `df2` and the whole range `0`-`2300000` is overlapping with the range of `62920`-`121705338`, it would be annotated with `Num` `3`.  Similarly, also the row 2 of `df1` has range `2300000`-`5400000` overlapping with the range of `62920`-`121705338`, row 2 would also be annotated with `Num` `3`.

However, in the case of the last row of `df1`, the range contains two rows from `df2`, so there needs to output the **sum** in `Num` in the last two rows of `df2`.

The desired output would be `df3`

```
df1.head()

|Start    |End      |Tag    |
|---------|---------|-------|
|0        |2300000  |gneg45 |   
|2300000  |5400000  |gpos25 |
|143541857|200000000|gneg34 |

df2.head()

| Start   |   End   |  Num   |
|---------|---------|--------|
|62920    |121705338|  3     |   
|143541857|147901334|  2     |
|147901760|151020217|  5     |


df3 = 

|Start    |End      |Num    |
|---------|---------|-------|
|0        |2300000  |3      |   
|2300000  |5400000  |3      |
|143541857|200000000|7      |
```

I tried pandas `merge` creating a key and `query` based on a range of columns, but nothing really worked.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description, you are looking for overlapping range in `df1` and `df2` in order for `df1` to take the `Num` value from `df2`.

To formulate the condition of overlapping range condition, let's illustrate as follows the **opposite condition** of ***non-overlapping range***:

Either:

```
                                         |<-------------->| 
                                      df2.Start       .df2.End
           |<------------->| 
        df1.Start       df1.End
```

or:

```
                 |<-------------->| 
              df2.Start       .df2.End
                                             |<------------->| 
                                          df1.Start       df1.End
```

This ***non-overlapping range condition*** can be formulated as:

Either (`df1.End` < `df2.Start`) or (`df1.Start` > `df2.End`)

Therefore, the **overlapping range condition**, being the **opposite**, is the **negation** of the above conditions, that is:

~ ((`df1.End` < `df2.Start`) | (`df1.Start` > `df2.End`))

which is equivalent to:

(`df1.End` >= `df2.Start`) & (`df1.Start` <= `df2.End`)

[Note: we deduce overlapping condition by considering the opposite and get the negation because the overlapping conditions have more scenarios. There are 4 cases: (1) `df1` covering the entire `df2` range and more; (2) `df1` being entirely contained within the `df2` range; (3) overlapping on left end only; (4) overlapping on right end only. We can simplify the logics by our approach.]

#### Solution 1: Simple Solution for small dataset

**Step 1:** For small dataset, you can cross join `df1` and `df2` by [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), then filter by the overlapping condition using [`.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), as follows:

```
df3 = (df1.merge(df2, how='cross', suffixes=('_df1', '_df2'))
          .query('(End_df1 >= Start_df2) & (Start_df1 <= End_df2)')
          .rename({'Start_df1': 'Start', 'End_df1': 'End'}, axis=1)
          [['Start', 'End', 'Num']]
      )
```

If your Pandas version is older than 1.2.0 (released in December 2020) and does not support merge with `how='cross'`, you can use:

```
df3 = (df1.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1), on='key', suffixes=('_df1', '_df2')).drop('key', axis=1)
          .query('(End_df1 >= Start_df2) & (Start_df1 <= End_df2)')
          .rename({'Start_df1': 'Start', 'End_df1': 'End'}, axis=1)
          [['Start', 'End', 'Num']]
      )
```

Intermediate result:

```
print(df3)

       Start        End  Num
0          0    2300000    3
3    2300000    5400000    3
7  143541857  200000000    2
8  143541857  200000000    5
```

**Step 2:**  Sum up the `Num` values for same range (same `Start` and `End`) by [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df3 = df3.groupby(['Start', 'End'])['Num'].sum().reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df3)

       Start        End  Num
0          0    2300000    3
1    2300000    5400000    3
2  143541857  200000000    7
```

#### Solution 2: Numpy Solution for large dataset

For large dataset and performance is a concern, you can use [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/theory.broadcasting.html) (instead of cross join and filtering) to speed up the execution time:

**Step 1:**

```
d1_S = df1.Start.to_numpy()
d1_E = df1.End.to_numpy()
d2_S = df2.Start.to_numpy()
d2_E = df2.End.to_numpy()

# filter for overlapping range condition and get the respective row indexes of `df1`, `df2` in `i` and `j`
i, j = np.where((d1_E[:, None] >= d2_S) & (d1_S[:, None] <= d2_E))

df3 = pd.DataFrame(
          np.column_stack([df1.values[i], df2.values[j]]),
          columns=df1.columns.append(df2.columns + '_df2')
      )
```

Intermediate result:

```
print(df3)

       Start        End     Tag  Start_df2    End_df2 Num_df2
0          0    2300000  gneg45      62920  121705338       3
1    2300000    5400000  gpos25      62920  121705338       3
2  143541857  200000000  gneg34  143541857  147901334       2
3  143541857  200000000  gneg34  147901760  151020217       5
```

**Step 2:**  Sum up the `Num` values for same range (same `Start` and `End`) by [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df3 = df3.groupby(['Start', 'End'])['Num_df2'].sum().reset_index(name='Num')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df3)

       Start        End  Num
0          0    2300000    3
1    2300000    5400000    3
2  143541857  200000000    7
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off the logic from @SeaBean, one option is with [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), followed by a groupby:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(
df1
.conditional_join(
    # add suffix here
    # to avoid MultiIndex, which happens
    # if the columns overlap
    df2.add_suffix('_y'), 
    # column from left, column from right, comparator
    ('Start', 'End_y', '<='), 
    ('End', 'Start_y', '>='))
.rename(columns={'Num_y':'Num'})
.groupby(['Start', 'End'], as_index = False)
.Num
.sum()
)
       Start        End  Num
0          0    2300000    3
1    2300000    5400000    3
2  143541857  200000000    7
```